# Can one purchase a SIM card at Bagan Nyaung-U Airport (NYU)?

Tags: airports, cellphones, myanmar, bagan, nyu

Can one purchase a SIM card at [Bagan Nyaung-U Airport (NYU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyaung_U_Airport)?

---

What I found so far:

I wasn't able to find any official website for Bagan Nyaung-U Airport (NYU).

I didn't find any information by Googling  [bagan nyaung-u airport sim card](https://www.google.com/search?q=bagan+nyaung-u+airport+sim+card&oq=Bagan+Nyaung-U+Airport+sim) aside from https://www.mmtimes.com/lifestyle/travel/1813-phone-rental-counter-opens-at-bagan-airport.html ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20191016025034/https://www.mmtimes.com/lifestyle/travel/1813-phone-rental-counter-opens-at-bagan-airport.html)) (published on 2016-10-16):

> A Mobile phone rental service aimed at tourists has been expanded to Bagan’s Nyaung-U airport, a spokesperson from Yatanarpon Mobile Rental Service said. 
>   Yatanarpon opened a counter at the airport next to the information counter on October 10, he said. […] SIM cards are US$2 a day, ordinary handsets $2 a day and smartphone handsets $4 a day. Customers must also pay a $50 deposit for a SIM card, $50 for an ordinary handset and $150 for a smartphone handset.

But that's the only place I found this information and I don't know whether 1) it is still available 2) I can use their SIM card without having to rent their phone.